# Wordpress - user specific custom taxonomies or categories. Link posts to specific pages

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm building a site using User Frontend Pro (http://wedevs.com/plugin/wp-user-frontend-pro/)to allow users to create their own post and pages from  the front end. The idea is to keep the site as simple as possible for people who find the back-end of WP a bit daunting.

The pages are the "Main" item, and then the posts are updates on this (Ie. The page is "My Car" and the posts are "Service history")

I want a way to allow users to to connect posts to the pages they create (and they may have multiple pages), and keep it user specific.

What I was thinking was to automatically assign a custom taxonomy to each page on creation, and have this visible only to the user who created the page. They can then assign this to any post, so they all group together in a category page.

The problem is I am not too sure how to go about:
a) Automatically creating the taxonomy 
b) Linking this only to the user who created it
c) If this is in fact the right way to do it

Answer (score 1):

WordPress [Author templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) seem to take care of item B and C. Taxonomies I'm not sure that you'd want an on-the-fly definition.

Answer (score 1):

One way is that you can change default role of all users.Make default role as editor from settings page in wp-admin.
Now users can create new posts,pages and can also edit their own pages.M not sure if they can publish there post at any given time .But you can check out roles and capabilities from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Now about linking your page you can always fetch author of particular posts.All you have to do is now check if author is only logged in and checking his post/page